# Wordpress PHP - Header not visible

Tags: php, html, wordpress-theming, mailchimp

I'm using Wordpress to create my website ([www.bonitasjourney.com](http://www.bonitasjourney.com)) and tried adding some text to the theme's header.php file to connect my page to Mailchimp. The theme I'm using is Twenty Seventeen.

After editing the file, my header is no longer visible on my page. I'm not very familiar with coding, could anyone take a look at the code to see if I accidentally deleted valuable information?

[Header code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgJDJ.png)

Thank you!